# Void pointer and their attribute constructor

Tags: c, ctf

I am supposed to find the vulnerability in the code (as a part of a ctf) and I feel it's hidden either in the `__attribute__((constructor))` or the pointer.

Here I can make out that it's a void pointer but I have never encountered a pointer with `()` (wasn't able to find out on the net either). So what type of a pointer is this and is the `(void(*)())` in `(void(*)())&name` for type casting or something else?

Also does the attribute constructor here play any role it feels like an empty default constructor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//Ignore this thing
__attribute__((constructor))
void setup(){
  setvbuf(stdout,NULL,2,0);
  setvbuf(stderr,NULL,2,0);
  setvbuf(stdin,NULL,2,0);
}

int main()
{
  printf("What's you name?\n");
  char name[100];
  fgets(name,100,stdin);
  void(*Kekpointer)() = (void(*)())&name;
  Kekpointer();
  return 0;
}
```

In short i just want more light on atttribute constructor and the pointer

edit:i got this hint "for challenge , your goal is to get a shell. Flag is stored on the remote server.  Read the source code carefully and try to find out the vulnerability. This is a beginner level challenge ", so i believe it could be a buffer overflow challenge but i am still not sure if the fgets function is involved

Comment: but if i recall correctly gets function is the buggy one (it overflows ) i did not know about the fgets function . i did try passing a string of length greater than 100 but it didnt give my ans(applying a logic similar to the gets function)  so what am i missing?

Comment: @zyked No it isn't.

Comment: Deleted my comment not to misguide anyone. You are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kekpointer is a function pointer that points to the address of the name varable.
So, when `Kekpointer();` executes, the instruction pointer (program counter) goes to the first byte of the name variable and continues execution from there.

There is no need for buffer overflow, you can just give the shellcode when it asks 'What's your name?'.

The difficult part however, is to find a shellcode that its bytes can be represented as ascii characters. Or find a way to input non printable characters.

Comment: yes i was able to figure it out that Kekpointer takes what we input as address so i tried giving hex values and NULL but none of them worked

Comment: No, it doesn't take what we input as address. It executes what we input as instructions. So what we input, must be something that if executed, should gives us a shell.